# Am having problems with my Permalink in my CMS program

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, content-management-system

Its not accepting Texts except Numeric figures. I created a Private method in my page.rb of my Model which is not callable from outside Model: page.rb so as to automatically fix in Permalink for users incase it's not provided. Despite, still not texts except numbers.

Here is few details about my code from my Model:

**page.rb**

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base

      belongs_to :subject
      has_many :sections
      has_and_belongs_to_many :editors, :class_name => 'AdminUser'

      acts_as_list :scope => :subject

      before_validation :add_default_permalink
      after_save :touch_subject

      validates_presence_of :name
      validates_length_of :name, :maximum => 255
      validates_presence_of :permalink
      validates_length_of :permalink, :within => 3..255
      # use presence_of with length_of to disallow spaces
      validates_uniqueness_of :permalink
      # for unique values by subject use ":scope => :subject_id"

      scope :visible, lambda {where(:visible => true)}
      scope :invisible, lambda {where(:visible => false)}
      scope :sorted, lambda {order('pages.position ASC')}
      scope :newest_first, lambda {order('pages.created_at DESC')}
      scope :search, lambda {|query| where('name LIKE ?', "%#{query}%")}

      private
        def add_default_permalink
          if permalink.blank?
            self.permalink = "#{id}-#{name.parameterize}"
          end
        end

        def touch_subject
          # touch is similar to:
          # subject.update_attributes(updated_at, Time.now)
          subject.touch
        end

    end
```

**See picture for the error here**

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qs2a.png)

if I add number up to 3 to this or put in just numbers, the program works well bet takes no text alone.

Comment: are you sure it is not an `integer` type?

Comment: what is type of permalink it your migration?

Comment: What am thinking is that it's take both Numeric/Integer and Alphanumeric.  I must have made mistake somewhere I can't figure out.